# Express get full url from a route file

Tags: node.js, express

So I have a route js file which handles all requests from a particular endpoint.I need to get the full url from within a middleware not the relative url however it seems not to be working. Here's my route file:

```
var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var router = express.Router();
var Member = require('../model/member');
var isAuthenticated = require('./middleware').isAuthenticated;

var responseData = {
    title: 'Dita Admin - Members',
    id: 'members',
    heading: 'Members',
    members: [],
    errors: {},
    create: true
};

/* GET members page. */
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
    Member.find({}, function (err, members) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            responseData.members = members;
        }

        res.render('members', responseData);
    });

});

module.exports = router;
```

Here's the middleware:

```
var isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }

    req.session.returnTo = req.path;
    console.log(req.session.returnTo);
    res.redirect('/login');
};

module.exports = {
    isAuthenticated: isAuthenticated
};
```

I keep getting `/` whenever i try to print the url. But the endpoint is `/members`.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `baseUrl` property placed on *request object* which gives you the URL path on which a router instance was mounted. So you could use:

#### [req.baseUrl](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.baseUrl)

for example in your members router:

```
router.get('/', isAuthenticated, function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.baseUrl); // /members
});
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that in the documentaion